# Why does it complain about `volume claim templates can only have their storage requests increased`?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes

I am deploying Elasticsearch cluster on Kubernetes in AWS EKS. The spec I have is:

```yaml
apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
kind: Elasticsearch
metadata:
  name: es
spec:
  version: 7.14.0
  nodeSets:
  - name: node
    count: 2
    config:
      node.store.allow_mmap: false
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        accessModes:
          - ReadWriteOnce
        storageClassName: ebs-sc
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 1024Gi
```

When I deploy I got this error:

`for: "es.yml": admission webhook "elastic-es-validation-v1.k8s.elastic.co" denied the request: Elasticsearch.elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co "es" is invalid: spec.nodeSet[0].volumeClaimTemplates: Invalid value: []v1.PersistentVolumeClaim{v1.PersistentVolumeClaim{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"elasticsearch-data", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), DeletionTimestamp:<nil>, DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ClusterName:"", ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, Spec:v1.PersistentVolumeClaimSpec{AccessModes:[]v1.PersistentVolumeAccessMode{"ReadWriteOnce"}, Selector:(*v1.LabelSelector)(nil), Resources:v1.ResourceRequirements{Limits:v1.ResourceList(nil), Requests:v1.ResourceList{"storage":resource.Quantity{i:resource.int64Amount{value:1099511627776, scale:0}, d:resource.infDecAmount{Dec:(*inf.Dec)(nil)}, s:"", Format:"BinarySI"}}}, VolumeName:"", StorageClassName:(*string)(0xc000cd2600), VolumeMode:(*v1.PersistentVolumeMode)(nil), DataSource:(*v1.TypedLocalObjectReference)(nil)}, Status:v1.PersistentVolumeClaimStatus{Phase:"", AccessModes:[]v1.PersistentVolumeAccessMode(nil), Capacity:v1.ResourceList(nil), Conditions:[]v1.PersistentVolumeClaimCondition(nil)}}}: volume claim templates can only have their storage requests increased, if the storage class allows volume expansion. Any other change is forbidden`

The spec includes `volumeClaimTemplates` which is used to claim the persistent storage. I don't understand why it says `volume claim templates can only have their storage requests increased, if the storage class allows volume expansion`.

I have checked PVC is empty:

```
$ kubectl get pvc
No resources found in default namespace.
```

And I have below spec for storage class:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
allowVolumeExpansion: true
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
```

Comment: Sounds like you try to make changes on the PVC. Do you already have a PVC with the same name in the cluster?

Comment: No i don't. All pvc have been deleted

Comment: do you have any other resources deployed, that might specify a VolumeClaimTemplate with name "elasticsearch-data" check especially custom resources like elasticsearch or statefulsets

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao does the accepted answer solve your problem?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

`...I don't understand why it says volume claim templates can only have their storage requests increased, if the storage class allows volume expansion.`

With ECK, when you applied a spec that referred a StorageClass that allows volume expansion, you can increase the storage size and re-apply the spec. Beside this **no other change** is allowed for the volumeClaimTemplates section. If you must change the volumeClaimTemplates (eg. refer a different StorageClass, reduce storage size), you need to also rename the name under `nodeSets` and re-apply the spec. Example:

```
...
spec:
  ...
  nodeSets:
  - name: <CHANGEME!>  # <-- MUST change if not a simple size increase
    ...
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: elasticsearch-data
      spec:
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: <xxxGi>  # <-- Can be increased if StorageClass supports expansion. To decrease the nodeSets name MUST be changed.
        storageClassName:<changeable only if nodeSets name is changed>
```

Comment: Can you explain why he needs this? He is only applying a static manifest

Comment: My storage class already have `allowVolumeExpansion` and I have attached the spec in the question

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, K8s has no idea how to change the storage class while retaining the data at the same time as the volumes have to change as well.

By changing the nodeset name, the old nodeset will disappear while the new nodeset will be able to be spawned from a clean state (assuming you're okay with not retaining the data in the old pods).

You can first rename the nodeset to a new name, let K8s flush and spawn new pods, then rename the nodeset back to the original name and repeat.

Answer (score 0):

If somebody hits this and additional note: If you have not previously added the correct volumeClaimTemplate for elasticsearch-data to the list during initial deployment you will end up in a state where you cannot increase the volume size. Workaround is to simply increase the size via kubectl and let kubernetes handle it. This Operator is a bit limted at the moment still.